# Reuse query from other model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is it possible to reuse query methods from different models?

I already have the following model:

```
class Profile
  belongs_to :user

  def self.search_by_name(search)
    # Some query code...
    # Returns Profile::ActiveRecord_Relation
  end
end
```

Now I want to implement a similar method: `User.search_by_name`.

```
class User
  has_one :profile

  def self.search_by_name(search)
    Profile.search_by_name(search).joins(table_name)
    # Should return User::ActiveRecord_Relation
  end
end
```

How can I make User.search_by_name to return `User::ActiveRecord_Relation`? Current solution is returning `Profile::ActiveRecord_Relation`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can only guess what you try to accomplish but I think your looking for `merge`

```
class User
  has_one :profile

  def self.search_by_name(search)
    joins(:profile).merge(Profile.search_by_name(search))
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [Concerns](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html).

`app/models/concerns/query.rb`

```
module Query
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  module ClassMethods
    def search_by_name(search)
      # Some query code...
    end
  end
end
```

Then `include Query` in your Profile and User models.

Comment: Good point -- removed. I guess I'm just used to seeing class methods written as self.method no matter what. Thanks. :-)

Comment: I did not provide much details when I wrote my question. The name attributes I search among is situated in the `Profile` table, so I cannot use the same query in both classes.